# How to stop USB flash drive hibernation partition

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, flash

My USB flash drive is not working. I don't know why. I may have used it to boost my PC and now when I plug it in my PC I cannot see it.

[image]

I want to use my USB flash drive again.

Comment: [Possible duplicate question](http://superuser.com/questions/359092/cannot-write-format-nor-erase-flash-drive)

Comment: Can you right click on it (the part on the right with the blue bar) and choose "delete volume"? If not, try `diskpart`, select the drive, and `clean` it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: I have been asking for a help regarding my USB flash drive. I think you have misdirected me and messed up my PC drive. What did we just do????? Did I mess up my computer??? My flash drive is still not working!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

DISKPART inbuilt utility from Windows manages memory partitions.
It can be invoked by entering "diskpart" in command prompt without quotes.

1. Press Start + r simultaneously
2. "cmd" and enter
3. Type "diskpart" and give elevated permissions
4. Type "list disk" to list available disks in system
5. Type "select disk ###" in console. ### is the number shown in list disk table
6. Type  "list part" to list all the partitions on disk
7. The hibernation partition is type "OEM"
8. Type "select part ###" in command prompt, ### is the partition number from partition table
9. Type "del part override" in to console. This will delete selected partition.

I have referred
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T/How-to-recover-8GB-partition-by-turning-Off-the-SSD-Intel-Rapid/ta-p/866737

Answer (score 1):

During Windows boot, it starts several software, utilities & services.
Most of the operations are done from RAM. Windows copies so many things from HDD to RAM. Most of the user program and Windows OS executes from RAM.

At the time of shutdown it closes all running software, utilities & services.

Most of user time is consumed during starting of system and own application.
In hibernation during system power off process Windows copies all RAM content in to HDD in "hiberfil.sys" file.
During system start it loads above file in to RAM instead of fresh boot sequence.

@Homer you can disable and re-enable hibernate option under Windows. It may resolve your problem.
Original Solution from Microsoft https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/920730

Run Command prompt in Admin mode.
To Disable Hibernation enter "powercfg.exe /hibernate off" without quotes
To Enable Hibernation enter "powercfg.exe /hibernate on" without quotes

Based on your responses I will say do it on your risk.
Here we provide solution to your question. We will respond to what you have asked.